# Why does amChart center the line with few data?

Tags: javascript, css, charts, amcharts

Look at this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2313ffbf/

data is generated by:

```
// generate some random data, quite different range
function generateChartData() {
    var chartData = [];
    // current date
    var firstDate = new Date();
    // now set 500 minutes back
    firstDate.setMinutes(firstDate.getDate() - 1000);

    // and generate data items
    var visits = 30; // <--- change this to 500
    for (var i = 0; i < visits; i++) {
        var newDate = new Date(firstDate);
        // each time we add one minute
        newDate.setMinutes(newDate.getMinutes() + i);
        // some random number
        visits += Math.round((Math.random()<0.5?1:-1)*Math.random()*10);
        // add data item to the array
        chartData.push({
            date: newDate,
            visits: visits
        });
    }
    return chartData;
}
```

And if you run it you can see the line graph isn't at the margins but centered.

If you change `var visits = 30;` to something like 500, then the line touch the margins.

How can I get that with few data too?

Comment: I am shocked you don't seem to be aware that you are required to post all your code that represents the problem here and not a jsfiddle: [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try being more specific in your chart configuration. So instead of `mm` (minutes) write `fff` (miliseconds):

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  ...
  "categoryAxis": {
    "minPeriod": "fff",
    "parseDates": true
  },
  ...
});
```

Find out more [here](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis).